# How can IntelliJ Idea automatically detect testng listeners in my maven project?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, testng

I have Maven project. It uses testng listener. I specify the listener in pom file, but when I try to run any test using green "play" button near it, IntelliJ creates run configuration without listeners and the test can't be run.
Yes, I can go to tab Listeners (see screenshot) and add my listener manually. In this way the test will be run correctly. The question is: is there a way to help Idea detect and add my listener automatically?
I can run test using Maven configuration and it works. So Maven correctly see my listener, which is specifyed in pom file in maven-surefire-plugin (see screenshot).

[image]

Thanks a lot for any help.

Answer (score 1):

IDE does not import this configuration from Maven automatically. Please [create a request for a feature](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA&c=Type%20Feature) and specify how you configure listeners in Maven, so that it would be clear how it can be taken from Maven.